# I had an import error with python on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have an import error with python on VS Code.
Although I had this error, I could run this code with no error.
Maybe, VS Code can not recognize the "import" statement.
I'm glad if anyone solve this problem.
Thank you.

Error on from statement :
Unable to import 'ClassSample'

[image]

main.py

```
#main.py

#path
sys.path.append('sampleClass/myClass')

#my class
from ClassSample import ClassSample  #error on from statement : Unable to import 'ClassSample'
```

ClassSample.py

```
#ClassSample.py

class ClassSample:

    #select param
    def selectParam(self, param):
        param = "_" + param
        return param
```

Comment: If you have to mess with `sys.path` your project is not structured or set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

The VSCode Intellisense can not analysis this code when linting:

```
sys.path.append("sampleClass/myClass")
```

So, it will prompt you with the `import error`.

---

This code can work because it's under the workspace folder directly. If you move `sampleClass` folder to another place, such as the `sample` folder, it will not work.

This is because you are using the relative path, it depends on the `cwd`-- `workspace folder path by default`.

Comment: Thanks. So should I use the absolute path to call my class?

Comment: @user65415642 It depends on you, it's not that much matter.

Comment: Thank you Steven. I would think again about the structure of my program with python. It seems to be different from java and php.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you confused yourself when importing.

You have to tell to python which directory you want to import a module. Since `main.py` is in another subdirectory, we need to move one folder up and locate the proper subdirectory hence the inclusion of `sampleClass` when importing.

```sh
from sampleClass.myClass import ClassSample
```

The above code worked when importing the class `ClassSample`. All you have to do now is to initialize it.

If you want a solution with minimal change, you could do:

```sh
from ..myClass.ClassSample import ClassSample
```

Where `..` is moving one directory up which means you are basically doing `sampleClass.myClass` here.

Sample Code.

```sh
# from sampleClass.myClass import ClassSample
from ..myClass.ClassSample import ClassSample

my_class = ClassSample
```

Comment: Python imports have no knowledge of directories. Relative imports can only navigate the _package_ structure, which need not match up with some directory tree. The OP doesn't appear to be organizing their code as a package, so relative imports do not apply.